# How to get ISO country code in google-libphonenumber Js package

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating new service, and need country ISO code based on mobile number. I am using google-libphonenumber package but in this package it giving information based on mobile and country ISO code.

I searched on google about this and offical npmjs site https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber but didn't get as per my requirement.

```
const phoneUtil = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();


const number = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput('7358469469', 'IN');
const number = phoneUtil.parse('7358469469');
```

***Expected result:*** I am expecting country ISO code based on mobile no.

***Actual result:*** parseAndKeepRawInput and parse function expecting mobile and country ISO code to return detail information.

Answer (score 2):

This is mission impossible, a phone number can be valid in various country. Phone number `7358469469` can be in India (`+91-7358469469`) or China (`+86-7358469469`) or any other countries.

However, if the phone number starts with `+`, you can parse the number and extract the country code, according to the country code specification. Please refer to https://countrycode.org/ for all countries' code list.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using the following code

```js
const getRegionCodeForNumber = (number, defaultCountryCode = 'US') => {
  const phoneUtil = i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance()
  const numberObj = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput(number, defaultCountryCode)
  return phoneUtil.getRegionCodeForNumber(numberObj)
}
```

Calling it like this:

```js
console.log(getRegionCodeForNumber('7358469469', 'IN'))
```

gives `IN`.

However @shaochuancs is right, to get something meaningful you'll need to pass the number in the international format starting with +, e.g.:

```js
console.log(getRegionCodeForNumber('+86-7358469469', 'IN'))
```

gives `CN`.

The second parameter of `getRegionCodeForNumber` is default country code which the function will fall back to when the international country code with + is omitted.